# Why doesn't increment operator work on chars always?

Tags: java, string, char, int

Why does this work:

```
char c = 5;
int i = c++;
```

But this throws a compiler error (Invalid Argument to Operator ++/--):

```
int i = argv[0].charAt(0)++;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `++` operator works on variables and expressions returning references to something writable, not on all values in general. In other words, there is simply no way to write the value of an incremented `char` back into the original string, so `charAt(0)++` is an error.

You can work around this problem by converting `argv[0]` to an array of characters, and incrementing a value inside that array.

Comment: Ah, I assumed it would just skip writing if it was a value and not a variable.

Comment: @Dgrin91 Java assumes that if you do not want writing, you would write `x` instead of `x++`, because the value to which the expression evaluates would be the same.

Answer (score 8):

The increment operator can only be applied to *lvalues*, which means expressions which evaluate to something that can appear on the left side of an assignment expression. Return value of a function is not an *lvalue*.

There is no connection between your `charAt(0)` call and the location in the underlying `char[]` wherefrom this char value was read. If you had

```
argv[0].value[0]++;
```

that would work, but `value` is

```
private final char[] value;
```

in the *immutable* String class.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put: it needs a variable. This is not a
variable `argv[0].charAt(0)` but a method call.